# When can lldb autocomplete expression?

Tags: xcode, lldb

Seems sometimes lldb can autocomplete a expression but sometimes this feature break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lldb command line has auto-completion for a bunch of commands and options, but not for the expressions you are typing in the `print` (i.e. `expr`) command.  If you are using Xcode, that will suggest auto-completions using its source analysis tools.  If you find instances where that isn't working, file a bug with http://bugreporter.apple.com and the Xcode folks can take a look.

Comment: Note that instead of using `print` one could use `frame variable` which does support autocomplete.

Comment: Indeed.  `print` brings the compiler & JIT engine in lldb online, which is very powerful, but that power isn't necessary for looking up an element of a local variable.  `frame variable` can do that job just as well and more efficiently.  It can also handle `foo.bar->baz` expressions.  I bet the vast majority of `print` usage could done with `f v`.  The caveat being that if you have `->` operators `frame variable` doesn't try to resolve those, and it doesn't do ObjC properties.    `print` uses the expression parser because it's an alias added for gdb users, and that's what the gdb command does.